# Constructing an object that's greater than any string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, comparison, sentinel

In Python 3, I have a list of strings and would find it useful to be able to append a sentinel that would compare greater than all elements in the list.

**Is there a straightforward way to construct such an object?**

I can define a class, possibly subclassing `str`, but it feels like there ought to be a simpler way.

For this to be useful in simplifying my algorithm, I need to do this ahead of time, before I know what the strings contained in the list are going to be (and so it can't be a function of those strings).

Comment: Do you need a specific implementation of `str.__gt__()` or you want to construct a `string` that results to greater than any other `string`?

Comment: You don't need to subclass `str`, and object would do, that implements the comparison operators accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of a naïve answer, but when you're dealing with numbers and need a sentinel value for comparison purposes, it's not uncommon to use the largest (or smallest) number that a specific number type can hold.

Python strings are compared lexicographically, so to create a "max string", you'd simply need to create a long string of the "max char":

```
MAX_CHAR = chr(sys.maxunicode)

# One million is entirely arbitrary here.
# It should ideally be 1 + the length of the longest possible string that you'll compare against 
MAX_STRING = MAX_CHAR * int(1e6)
```

Unless there's weird corner cases that I'm not aware of, `MAX_STRING` should now be considered greater than any other string (other than itself); provided that it's long enough.

Comment: Why bother making it long? If that's correct at all, which it probably is because of the probably not otherwise used character, then length 1 suffices.

Comment: @KellyBundy I made it long for the odd chance that they had a string starting with `\U0010ffff` characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can inline objects of a custom class:

```py
from functools import total_ordering

M = total_ordering(type('maxstring', (), {'__lt__': lambda *_: False}))()

print(sorted([M, 'abc', M, 'zyx']))
# ['abc', 'zyx', <__main__.maxstring object>, <__main__.maxstring object>]
```

Unfortunately, if you're going to inline this object more than once, and want to make sure that multiple maxstring objects compare equal, you should fix its comparison `==` operator:

```py
M1 = total_ordering(type('maxstring', (), {'__lt__': lambda *_: False}))()
M2 = total_ordering(type('maxstring', (), {'__lt__': lambda *_: False}))()

print(M1 == M1)
# True
print(M1 == M2)
# False

M1 = total_ordering(type('maxstring', (), {'__lt__': lambda *_: False, '__eq__': lambda s,o: type(o).__name__=='maxstring'}))()
M2 = total_ordering(type('maxstring', (), {'__lt__': lambda *_: False, '__eq__': lambda s,o: type(o).__name__=='maxstring'}))()

print(M1 == M2)
# True
```

**Important note:** Do not make your maxstring an instance of `str`, otherwise it will be treated half like a maxstring and half like an empty string, and this will mess up the comparisons:

```py
M = total_ordering(type('maxstring', (str,), {'__lt__': lambda *_: False}))()

print(isinstance(M, str))
# True
print(sorted([M, 'abc', M, 'zyx']))
# ['', 'abc', '', 'zyx']

print((M < 'abc'), (M > 'abc'), ('abc' < M), ('abc' > M))
# False False False False
```

Answer (score 2):

For fun, here's an hack that depends on implementation details. I build a character/string that's not possible without such a hack:

```
import ctypes

# From https://stackoverflow.com/a/62188431
def deref(addr, typ):
    return ctypes.cast(addr, ctypes.POINTER(typ))

# Largest allowed character
S = chr(0x10FFFF)

# Make it larger
deref(id(S), ctypes.c_int)[18] += 1
```

Let's take it for a spin:

```
import random

# Show that it's indeed 0x110000
print(hex(ord(S)))

# Test that it's larger than all others
chars = [S, *map(chr, range(0x110000))]
for _ in range(3):
    random.shuffle(chars)
    print(max(chars) is S)

# Show that it's normally impossible
chr(ord(S))
```

Output ([try it](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZHPTgIxEMbjtU8xCQdbRZYVYzYkHCXxosblRgip2y7duLvdTAeBZ_HCRd_FV_BpbKEYD85x_nzfb2beP7sdGdvu9x9rKq-y77OvquksEhS067RjrAdTtA0Yos6Nk8SRLF7tm8aytptBYZtEJrfXaZbdjFKmdAlKoy65VAr74CXEmIEP1LTGNooOCukotsTM0-P9w-zumYcJwVgOEygM8uE2HU59CHaUrRTPxe9QsaxaEvM0W8DlBFLGWGRH2SrbBPbc2A2QkQQVnTuoWqW1Ai-bDn2wDr0CN3rLLQbp4N2DmXb0Z6iWuNIYEi3IugZLRqNjhZHoPOc878NFIzvugfvBeqX5yUCIBSstwtI7x9LodJED48CZdVnWmh_UxKFyhGrkNiahcpCLf7ZpLTYeaAdhbeeql1qzcLW4y_Gj8bGnB_8A)):

```
0x110000
True
True
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ATO/code", line 18, in <module>
    chr(ord(S))
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)
```