# Clarification for "it should be possible to change the value of 1" from the CPython documentation

Tags: python, implementation, cpython

See this link: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256; when you create an int in that range, you actually just get back a reference to the existing object. **So, it should be possible to change the value of 1. I suspect the behavior of Python, in this case, is undefined**. :-)

What do the **bold** lines mean in this context?

Comment: Note that the bold part of above quote (which the question is about) has been removed from the documention in Python 3.9.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It means that integers in Python are actual objects with a "value"-field to hold the integer's value.  In Java, you could express Python's integers like so (leaving out a lot of details, of course):

```java
class PyInteger {

    private int value;

    public PyInteger(int val) {
        this.value = val;
    }

    public PyInteger __add__(PyInteger other) {
        return new PyInteger(this.value + other.value);
    }
}
```

In order to not have hunderts of Python integers with the same value around, it caches some integers, along the lines of:

```java
PyInteger[] cache = {
  new PyInteger(0),
  new PyInteger(1),
  new PyInteger(2),
  ...
}
```

However, what would happen if you did something like this (let's ignore that `value` is private for a moment):

```java
PyInteger one = cache[1];  // the PyInteger representing 1
one.value = 3;
```

Suddenly, every time you used `1` in your program, you would actually get back `3`, because the object representing `1` has an effective value of `3`.

Indeed, you can do that in Python!  That is: it is possible to change the effective numeric value of an integer in Python.  There is an answer in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2441cv/can_you_change_the_value_of_1/).  I copy it here for completeness, though (original credits go to *Veedrac*):

```py
import ctypes

def deref(addr, typ):
    return ctypes.cast(addr, ctypes.POINTER(typ))

deref(id(29), ctypes.c_int)[6] = 100
#>>> 

29
#>>> 100

29 ** 0.5
#>>> 10.0
```

The Python specification itself does not say anything about how integers are to be stored or represented internally.  It also does not say which integers should be cached, or that any should be cached at all.  In short: there is nothing in the Python specifications *defining* what should happen if you do something silly like this ;-).

---

We could even go slightly further...

In reality, the field `value` above is actually an array of integers, emulating an arbitrary large integer value (for a 64-bit integer, you just combine two 32-bit fields, etc).  However, when integers start to get large and outgrow a standard 32-bit integer, caching is no longer a viable option.  Even if you used a dictionary, comparing integer arrays for equality would be too much of an overhead with too little gain.

You can actually check this yourself by using `is` to compare identities:

```py
>>> 3 * 4 is 12
True
>>> 300 * 400 is 120000
False
>>> 300 * 400 == 120000
True
```

In a typical Python system, there is exactly one object representing the number `12`.  `120000`, on the other hand, is hardly ever cached.  So, above, `300 * 400` yields a new object representing `120000`, which is different from the object created for the number on the right hand side.

Why is this relevant?  If you change the value of a small number like `1` or `29`, it will affect all calculations that use that number.  You will most likely seriously break your system (until you restart).  But if you change the value of a large integer, the effects will be minimal.

Changing the value of `12` to `13` means that `3 * 4` will yield `13`.  Chaning the value of `120000` to `130000` has much less effect and `300 * 400` will still yield (a new) `120000` and not `130000`.

As soon as you take other Python implementations into the picture, things can get even harder to predict.  [MicroPython](https://micropython.org/), for instance, does not have objects for small numbers, but emalutes them on the fly, and [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/) might well just optimise your changes away.

Bottomline: the exact behaviour of numbers that you tinker with is truly undefined, but depends on several factors and the exact implementation.

---

*Answer to a question in the comments: What is the significance of `6` in Veedrac's code above?*

All objects in Python share a common memory layout.  The first field is a *reference counter* that tells you how many other objects are currently referring to this object.  The second field is a reference to the object's *class* or *type*.  Since integers do not have a fixed size, the third field is the size of the data part (you can find the relevant definitions [here (general objects)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/232dda6cbc10860328a83517a6e3ea238ff4147f/Include/object.h#L115) and [here (integers/longs)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/232dda6cbc10860328a83517a6e3ea238ff4147f/Include/longintrepr.h#L85)):

```
struct longObject {
    native_int      ref_counter;  // offset: +0 / +0
    PyObject*       type;         // offset: +1 / +2
    native_int      size;         // offset: +2 / +4
    unsigned short  value[];      // offset: +3 / +6
}
```

On a 32-bit system, `native_int` and `PyObject*` both occupy 32 bits, whereas on a 64-bit system they occupy 64 bits, naturally.  So, if we access the data as 32 bits (using `ctypes.c_int`) on a 64-bit system, the actual value of the integer is to be found at offset `+6`.  If you change the type to `ctypes.c_long`, on the other hand, the offset is `+3`.

Because `id(x)` in CPython returns the memory address of `x`, you can actually check this yourself.  Based on the above `deref` function, let's do:

```py
>>> deref(id(29), ctypes.c_long)[3]
29
>>> deref(id(29), ctypes.c_long)[1]
10277248
>>> id(int)       # memory address of class "int"
10277248
```

Comment: @Toblas Thanks for the great answer!! Just want to ask out of curiosity: If I change ```29``` to ```100``` in the Python script, does this also mean that the corresponding changes will be visible in the imported module as well?

Comment: @NSR  Yes, the integers are cached globally and any such change would affect everything you do in that interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Since the object is returned by reference, then if you change the object it will change for everything in the program.

So taking the value 1 as an example, you could change it to 42.
This is only possible because the C API gives you internal access to the Python interpreter; it feels unlikely you could do this from within a Python script itself (without using something like cffi for example).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about what would happen if you “changed the value at 1’s address to 17” in the internals is just printing each element in `range(3)`— you would see 0, 17, 2.

Comment: I just tried. You'd only see 0, because you iterate between 0 and 2 with a step of 17.